# What is wrong with this answer? (SO)

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) answer on SO and it have a wrong formatting. Why it look so ugly?

Comment: It is not ugly. It is a piece of art!

Comment: Did you read the notice at the bottom of the post? *"The post looks exactly as it is supposed to look - there are no problems with its content."*

Comment: That answer is sacred. Don't even think about thinking about touching it. Think about kittens instead. Ḍ̯̲̀o͙̜ ̴͍̼̙̦̘̝n̠͘o̯͎͘t҉̹͙̟͇̼ ̰͙̺̥̖̘͖to̫͓̼͎͔̩͕u̫c̬͇̗̝̗͇̕h̗ ̩̠̟̠͎̝̩t҉̩̼̻͓̗̯h͔̝̥̞͙̘͠e͈̙͘ ̮͎̲̥̠a͎͔n̷͕̥͍̦s͓̤͇͇͎w̨̞̩̗͚̤͚͇ḛr̜͕͍͚̖̭̰ ͞f̼̱o̥̫͖͓r͜ ̴̠i̻̖̞͕͚͎̗͡t͎͉͘ ̶w̺̲̯̜i̵̖̹l̠̙̘͎̘̣l̹̖̻̪̲̰̦͡ ͘b̻̭͓͞i͎̞ț̵̭̘e̡ ̞you̠̯͔̳̕

Comment: As @slugster points out, don't mess with **T**O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ T**H̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡**

Answer (score 6):

That formatting is done intentionally; the answerer used a [Zalgo text generator](http://www.eeemo.net/) to get the result.